# Unit Real Space?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Is there a formal name for a space that is the positive orthant of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where each of the $n$ dimensions is bounded to lie between zero and unity? The 1D representation would be a line segment between zero and unity, the 2D representation would be a unit square, 3D a unit cube, etc. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Unit hypercube if you want to be fancy, but I'd just say 'cube.'

Comment: Spivak calles it the unit $n$-cube.